# Informatica job scheduling scripting in unix

Tags: bash, scheduling

There are 4 shell scripts:

1. Migrate a file from path-A to path-B (unix).
2. This script triggers one powercenter work flow.
3. This script triggers one IDQ job.
4. This script deletes the file from path-B (refer point-1 script)

Now I need to create a shell script to call above mentioned scripts in sequence (Any script shall not start before previous is completed successfully).

I am absolutely new to unix.

Comment: Can you please provide more details? As it stands, this a very generic question and is unlikely to give you helpful answers. Details like how the scripts are executed currently, whether they need to be called from a particular directory, etc would be helpful.

Comment: script1 && script2 && script3 && script4

Comment: @munircontractor... Currently each script has to be triggered manually using bash.. Yes all scripts exist in a directory and called from same dir

Answer (score 1):

```
#! /bin/sh -
script1 &&
 script2 &&
 script3 &&
 script4
```

`cmd1 && cmd2` runs `cmd2` only if `cmd1` succeeds. The exit status of a script is the exit status of the last run command.

Or:

```
#! /bin/sh -
set -e
script1
script2
script3
script4
```

`set -e` tells the shell to exit whenever a command fails (with the exit status of the failing command).

Or:

```
#! /bin/sh -
script1 || exit
script2 || exit
script3 || exit
script4
```

`cmd1 || cmd2` runs `cmd2` if `cmd1` fails. `exit` exits the shell with the exit status of the last command (so here of the failing script). You can use `exit 1` to force the exit status to be 1.

Comment: Thanks Stephane.. I shall try these.. Will keep you posted (tomorrow.. I am off work now)